# How to search and replace the last occurrence of special character in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I want to achieve this :

I want to change this

```
./Dir/file_name1/abc.
./Dir/file_name2/def.
./Dir/file_name3/xyz.
./Dir/file_name4/pqr.
```

to

```
./Dir/file_name1/database_file
./Dir/file_name2/database_file
./Dir/file_name3/database_file
./Dir/file_name4/database_file
```

in `vim` . I am new to regular expressions in `vim` so please could you help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Issue the following ex-command:

```
:%s,[^/]*$,database_file
```

The regular expression `[^/]*$` matches the last part that does not contains `/`.

Demo: http://asciinema.org/a/10005

Comment: That's nicer than my approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\(.*\/\).*/\1database_file/
```

The expression:

```
\(      # start group 1
  .*    #   anything, up to the end of the line
  \/    #   a forward slash (this backtracks to the last slash on the line)
\)      # end group 1
.*      # anything, up to the end of the line
```

Answer (score 1):

And a `:normal` solution because finding the right regular expression can take too much damn time (it's a fun way to waste one's time, though):

```
:%norm $T/Cdatabase_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another vim tips&tricks (`if has('python')`):

```
:py from vim import current
:py from os.path import dirname, join
:%s/.*/\=pyeval('join(dirname(current.line), "database_file")')/
```

Comment: Now without Python: `:%s/.*/\=fnamemodify(submatch(0), ':h').'/database_file'/`

Answer (score 0):

```
 %s/\(\d\)\/\S\+$/\1\/database_file/g
```

the expression in the parantheses matches the integer at the end of file_name at every line and will be used for back referencing while replacing the matched part with the required term 'database_file'